# Getting error while installing scrapy in ubuntu

Tags: python, scrapy, ubuntu-15.04

I want to install scrapy for my project in ubunu. i used pip to install scrapy but i always getting this error while installing.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==1.5.6', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 558, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2682, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2355, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2361, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 74, in <module>
    from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/vcs/mercurial.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip.download import path_to_url
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 22, in <module>
    import requests, six
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 53, in <module>
    from .packages.urllib3.contrib import pyopenssl
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 53, in <module>
    import OpenSSL.SSL
  File "/home/karthick/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import rand, crypto, SSL
  File "/home/karthick/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 112, in <module>
    if _lib.Cryptography_HAS_SSL_ST:
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Cryptography_HAS_SSL_ST'
```

so how do i get rid of this error and install scrapy

Comment: First of all update your pip using `sudo pip install --upgrade pip` then take a look at [scrapy documentatin](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html#things-that-are-good-to-know) Then install the missing dependencies. In your case you have to install `pyOpenSSL` using: `sudo pip install pyOpenSSL` then try to install scrapy again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should update your pip first, then try again.
I see `pip==1.5.6`, omg, it's older than the moon

Comment: :D i don't think that is a problem

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me (although with Anaconda, not `pip`).

I tracked it down to updating pyopenssl from 16.0 to 16.2.

My solution was to first reinstall Anaconda (which reverted pyopenssl to 16.0). *(You may not need to do this.)*

After that, I just ran

```
sudo apt install python3-openssl
```

After doing this, my problem seemed to be corrected.

Comment: I had the same `AttributeError` when I wanted to run a jupyter notebook. After updating python3-openssl as suggested, jupyter works!